# Trap and translate ESC/P2 printer output

Tags: printing, decompiler

Old days are catching up and old stuff isn't as good as new. Have tons of data stored in a system that only supports printing to ESC/P2 printer language, and even if that isn't completely unsupported, I want to be able to convert the printouts.

The datastorage is a properitary file. I have decoded some of the fileformat, but still there is too many blanks to successfully recreating the stored data.

The software is written in Forth. Tried to debug it, but it's too timeconsuming without a better decompiler. Any pointers...?

At last, the easy way out is to grab the printout stream and decode it into bitmaps and then create a PDF or something. Even if ESC/P2 is older I havent found a good library for it. Any pointers?

If anyone has suggestions to what path to walk I'd be very happy. Oh, and any software I write to solve this will be written in C#. :)

Comment: Did you find out the way to do this? 
I want to know the same thing. if you got that before, can you help me a little bit?

Comment: Witch part of the question? :)